# How to Create Variables from OLS Regression Results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Madrid','Lisbon','Madrid','London','Tokyo','London','Tokyo'], 
     'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Bitcoin','Master Card','Bitcoin','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Bitcoin'],
     'Client Number':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
     }

d = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index('Client Number')

df = pd.get_dummies(d,prefix='', prefix_sep='')


X = df[['Lisbon','London','Madrid','New York','Tokyo','Bitcoin','Master Card','Visa','No','Yes']]
Y = df['Total']

X1 = sm.add_constant(X)
reg = sm.OLS(Y, X1).fit()

reg.summary()
```

[image]

I want to import the coef of each variable in order to apply the model to new data. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reg.params` contains the parameter estimates. Other quantities presented in the summary are available in `reg.bse` (standard errors), `reg.tvalues` (t-statistics) and `reg.pvalues` (P-values).

The full set of available properties can be seen in the documentation:

https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html

If you want to apply the same parameters to a different dataset, the simplest method is to construct a new OLS model with the new data, e.g.,

```
mod = OLS(y_new, x_new)
```

and then use the `predict` method,

```
mod.predict(reg.params)
```

where `res.params` are from your original fit. Note that is must be the case that x_new has the same variables in the same location as in the original regression.